# Printing php array items by sets

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a php associative array of 24 items. I wanted to loop through them and print 4 rows each having 6 columns.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi Wikki. Just had a quick look through some of your old questions, and you've been rather lucky - a few upvotes and no downvotes, despite a number of brief questions of this kind. So you know, we really like it when questions are presented with evidence of prior research and effort. This question at least would benefit from a code snippet containing the associative array you have. Secondly, some context would be helpful - the answers below assume you are in a web process, but you could be using the console. More detail = better answers!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(As an example i used an array with numbers and added the key)

```
<?php

    $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24);
    $count = 1;

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {

        echo sprintf(" Key: %3d Value %3d", $k, $v);

        if($count % 6 == 0)
            echo "<br />";

        $count++;
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
Key: 0 Value 1 Key: 1 Value 2 Key: 2 Value 3 Key: 3 Value 4 Key: 4 Value 5 Key: 5 Value 6
Key: 6 Value 7 Key: 7 Value 8 Key: 8 Value 9 Key: 9 Value 10 Key: 10 Value 11 Key: 11 Value 12
Key: 12 Value 13 Key: 13 Value 14 Key: 14 Value 15 Key: 15 Value 16 Key: 16 Value 17 Key: 17 Value 18
Key: 18 Value 19 Key: 19 Value 20 Key: 20 Value 21 Key: 21 Value 22 Key: 22 Value 23 Key: 23 Value 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$columns = 6;
$count = $columns;
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    print $v.", ";
    $count--;
    if (!$count) {
        print "<br/>";
        $count = $columns;
    }
 }
```